# Git creates a .git folder instead of a soft symbolic link

Tags: git, github, workflow

With all the net publicity of how great git is over the existing repositories that we had been used to like SourceSafe or MKS etc. I decided to use it for a project of mine.

It is bad practice to host your repository (aka .git) within the same folders that you work in - you could accidentally overwrite your repo and I thought that I could have hosted it external to my coding directories. On searching for advice on google, I was directed to stackoverflow - where I was advised to symbolically soft link (connect) my external .git repository to my coding directories. So, this is what I did

`C:/my_codebase/.git was where i had done and init and created my git repo`
`c:/eclipseWorkSpace/my_codeProject was where I ran these git commands using the bash git shell`

`My Git Install was Git-1.9.0-preview20140217`

STEP 1 Trying to create a shortcut or symbolic link to my real repo hoping that git would be fooled into thinking that it is working with a real .git folder within my code base

`$ ln -s 'C:/my_codebase/.git' '.'
ln: creating symbolic link ./.git' toC:/tasha_codebase/.git': Permission denied`

STEP 2 - i thought it had not been created - noticed in fact it had created a FRESH .git directory instead which was not even symbolically linked/connected to the real repo I was trying - hence the message I recvd below when I thought of executing the command again thinking that the single quotes around my dot for curr directory was wrong.

`` $ ln -s 'C:/my_codebase/.git' .
ln: `./.git': cannot overwrite directory ``

If I was a buying a car as a consumer from the makers from git - I would have asked for my money back long ago. At least the DSL for a car is intuitive - WhatYouThinkIsWhatYouGet - you want to turn right you turn the steering wheel to the right - you dont spend nights figuring out why it has not turned right.

So, what am I doing wrong ? 
Is there a DVCS repo out there which has collaborative processes like GitHub that allows external working directories -- EASILY -- without having to LEARN all this symbolic doodah workarounds ?

After all thinking so much is like work - which is stopping us from coding which is like playing.

Comment: `It is bad practice to host your repository (aka .git) within the same folders` who said so, and where?

Comment: Also, you are trying to create symbolic links on windows which is not possible.

Comment: so accidental deletion of your repo folder hosted within your working directory or the risk of that happening does not exist ???? In all other VCS's the repositories are always hosted in a separate area from one's working directory.

Comment: That's pretty much the reason for using github - as a central source - even if you accidentally delete it, you can re-clone it quickly from github. If you think it is still necessary, you can setup an intermediate `bare` repository on your server for avoiding such scenarios - basically pull from github into this bare repo, and pull from the bare repo into your actual repo.

Comment: mu 無 - was under the impression that since I was using a windows unixsy mingw32 environment which is what the git bash command line interpreter uses - it would translate it using shortcut.lnk's - obviously not I guess - as you say

Comment: @user1561783, no Git for Windows does not support symlinks (in any form) and it's very unlikely it will ever do that (due to a number of purely technical reasons). Cygwin's Git (in Cygwin environments) *might* support them though. But using it means all the attached strings of using the Cygwin environment -- you might or might not want to do that.

Comment: @user1561783, I don't buy that "so accidental deletion of your repo folder hosted within your working directory or the risk of that happening does not exist ????" argument: there's this risk of accidentally deleting *any* directory on your computer -- no matter where it's located.  So there's only one method to mitigate the possibility of accidental deletion: *have backups.*  With a DVCS system this usually means "push your work somewhere".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the work-tree and git-dir parameters and corresponding environment variables?

```
git --work-tree=XXXX-checkout clone XXXX
```

will put what would have been in .git in XXXX and the checkout of your working directory will be in  XXXX-checkout. If you now set your environment up to point to the two locations, thus

```
export GIT_WORK_TREE=$PWD/XXX-checkout
export GIT_DIR=$PWD/XXXX
```

you can then work (fairly) normally with your checkout.

Comment: Thanks slobobaby - I used the following resolve it  <code>git --work-tree='c:/myWorkinDir' add 'c:/myWorkinDir'</code> whilst I was in my C:/my_codebase/ folder which was where I wanted to my repo to be  - Though I am unable to understand what GIT_DIR is going to provide and whether it is different from GIT_WORK_TREE

Comment: GIT_DIR is where the contents of the .git directory is placed and what it is called. GIT_WORK_TREE is where the checked out files are placed.